# Azure Pipeline PowerShell Script Error "A path to a .ps1 file is required"

Tags: azure-pipelines, powershell-2.0

I've created an Azure pipeline and have a powershell@2 task that I created using the standard wizard.

```
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: "Simple Script"
    inputs:
      targetType: filePath
      filePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/simplescript.ps2'
      arguments: 'version'
```

however, I get an error "##[error]Invalid file path '/home/vsts/work/1/s/simplescript.ps2'  A path to a .ps1 file is required." when I run the pipeline.

Why would a PowerShell@2 task look for a .ps1 file?

Initially, I assumed that the problem was related to how I referenced the file and that the working directory may not be set correctly.  I've put an inline step before this one and that seems to confirm the variable is set correctly and the file path is valid.

I then renamed the target file to simplescript.ps1 and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why would a PowerShell@2 task look for a .ps1 file?

All powershell scripts should have the .ps1 extension. The @2 refers to the task version, and has nothing to do with powershell versioning or file extensions.

Similarly, the AzurePowershell@5 task should have a .ps1 powershell script.